# Sprite positioning at wrong points in y axis

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

so I know this is a dumb question, but maybe it'll help other people like me out too. Basically, I'm making a sprite appear at the top of the screen and then move to the bottom but in a random x position. There's nothing wrong with moving to the random x position, the problem is that it doesn't start out at the top of the screen. Here is my code:

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "comet")
sprite.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 100)
sprite.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: 0)
sprite.zPosition = 100
self.addChild(sprite)                                  `

let randomNum = CGPoint(x:Int (arc4random() % 1000), y: 1)
let actionMove =  SKAction.moveTo(randomNum, duration: 1)   
let actionComet = SKAction(actionMove)  
sprite.runAction(actionComet)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are placing your sprite at location `(0,0)` which is left bottom of the screen. If you want to place the sprite at the top use:

```
sprite.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height + sprite.size.height / 2.0)
```

Comment: I'm receiving the error "cannot convert value of CGSize to expected argument CGFloat"  I rewrote the line completely as well.

Comment: Where exactly do you see this error? can you show your modification?